# How do I find the first token after an arbitrary character offset in a spaCy document?

Tags: spacy

I have a spaCy document and an arbitrary character offset *n* in that document? How do I find the first token boundary following that offset, i.e. the smallest *m ≥ n* such that *m* is the start of a token?

Is there some way to do this with the spaCy interface other than looping through all the tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question 1: Token Offset

```
How do I find the first token boundary following that offset...
```

for any object in sPacy there is a `.text` field. so `Tokens` and `Documents` can be used with this raw text field.

In addition, sPacy provides two ways to get offsets for tokens.

1. `i` the index in the list of tokens
2. `idx` the raw char offset of the `.text`

So in your example I believe you just want something like the following:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> doc = nlp("here is a document with tokens in it")
>>> for token in doc:
...     if token.idx > n:
...             m = token.idx
...             break
... 
>>> m
19
>>> doc.text[m]
'w'
>>> token.i
4
>>> token
with
>>>
```

## Question 2: Find without loop

```
Is there some way to do this ... other than looping ...
```

Sadly, I do not believe there is any other interface on the `Document` level that allows for finding tokens via char offset.